# How do I remove the aurora from an image to enhance the background stars?

Tags: image-processing, denoising

Most auroral pictures are post-processed and enhance the aurora to such an extent that you don't see the background stars. Suppose I have a photo of the night sky with an aurora, taken with my phone or any camera. What method should I use to do the opposite - fade the actual aurora as much as possible and enhance the background stars? I've tried sharpening and denoising but I'm completely new to the field so my attempts have been rather poor.

Comment: If the problem is similar to enhancing detail from within a varying shadow, this *"homomorphic processing"* we had in Oppenheim and Schafer was pretty good.  First compute the logarithm of the image magnitude (this separates the multiplication of shadow x detail into an addition), then high-pass filter that (perhaps transforming to frequency domain, applying HPF, and inverse transforming).  Lastly undo the logarithm with an exponential.